# AngularJS $broadcast not working properly in IE/Edge browsers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following codes that does not work properly in IE/Edge for some reason. I am using AngularJS version 1.5.0.

In my service `someservice.js` I have the following codes:

```
   // Codes to do something here before broadcasting changes
   $rootScope.$broadcast("updateMade");
```

In my controller, my codes look something like this:

```
angular.module(‘app’).controller(“someCtrl”, function($scope, $stateParams, someservice) {

var vm = this;
vm.id = $stateParams.someID; // This id is used to search for a content of a specific type

var doSomething = function(id) {
    someservice.getData(id).then(function(data) { // getData function makes a request to API to fetch data
    vm.dataArea = data; // assigns data to the view
  });
};
  doSomething(vm.id); // First gets called to render the view

  // Methods create, delete, update not shown here, but they all broadcast the message updateMade upon being called

  $scope.$on(“updateMade”, function() {
    doSomething(vm.id);
  });


});
```

Why doesn't IE/Edge pick up on the broadcast? This does not seem to be an issue in any other browsers.

Comment: Do you see an error in the browser console of any kind? And are you sure the event is never received, or is that the doSomething() function just isn't doing anything? If you put a trace right above "doSomething()", do you see it in the console? 

Also, where is "doSomething()"? It is possible you're bobbling JS scoping (which remember doesn't work like usual block scoping) and that "doSomething" simply isn't found to exist? I get that you say "only not in IE", but it'd be good to check a few things first.

Comment: What version of AngularJS do you use?

Comment: @TimConsolazio No errors in any browsers were found, including IE/Edge. doSomething() is a function that gets called to update the view live. I have tried putting a console.log("Test") above doSomething(), but saw no outputs in IE/Edge. The service and controller are in different files, but the service gets injected into the controller, so I don't think there are any scoping issues that I am aware of.

Comment: Looks like you'd have to post the code. I've run into IE issues with angular related to things like ng-style, but never had a problem like this (which doesn't mean they don't exist). The code sir!

Comment: @TimConsolazio I have provided more code, please let me know if you need more info.